# How to change TimePicker format using properties

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker

I've used TimePicker format in my wpf application using extended wpf toolkit. I'm using "HH:MM" format. but problem is, the button which allows to select hours directly from the options, showing 24 hours format, but I want 12 hours only. But I managed that through properties of TimePicker by changing Endtime from "23:59" to "11:59". But those up and down buttons still showing hours upto 23. so, If I want to make upto 11, what should I do? Can I achieve this by TimePicker's property only? also It's not showing part of day i.e AM/PM. I also want another button which should show me these two options (i.e AM and PM). Please suggest, how should I proceed?

My Timepicker controls which are bound to DateTime object in my code behind are as follows,

```
<Window x:Class="TimeSheet.CustomView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    x:Name="Time"
    Title="CustomView" Width="596" Height="596">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Width="596" Margin="0,137,-8,399">
        <xctk:TimePicker x:Name="StartTimeText" Value="{Binding starttime, ElementName=Time, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Yellow" Width="113" EndTime="11:59:0" AllowSpin="False"/>
        <xctk:TimePicker x:Name="StopTimeText" Value="{Binding stoptime, ElementName=Time, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Yellow" Width="115" EndTime="11:59:0" AllowSpin="False"/>
    </StackPanel>              
</Grid>
</Window>
```

UI of my Window-

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `FormatString` property to format your display. I think you have the formats covered in your previous questions. You should also set `Format` to `Custom`.

Here's a suggestion:

```
<xctk:TimePicker Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm:ss tt" />
```

You should note that using `HH` for hours gives you 24-hour format, while `hh` will give you a 12-hour format.

You can check the documentations [here](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/TimePicker).

Comment: But there is no TimeFormatString property for this control. It's FormatString property. I've FormatString property but, it's not showing part of day (i.e AM/PM).

Comment: Sorry I got it mixed up with `DateTimePicker`. I've edited the answer

Comment: Now, It's showing only AM part of the day. That means showing from 1:00 AM to 12:00 AM

Comment: Didn't you set the `EndTime` property to get that behaviour?

Comment: `Correct` is subjective to your requirement. What is your requirement? The `StartTime` and `EndTime` properties merely limit the items in the drop-down.

Comment: Sorry, I've not checked drop downs properly. It spins properly from AM to PM. It solved my problem.